# Ошибка в приложении Apple Developer App

Tags: apple, account

После заполнения формы адреса проживания выскакивает ошибка "Contact us for continue", далее служба поддержки запрашивает паспорт и возобновляет доступ к аккаунту, далее опять происходит блокировка аккаунта после ввода адреса. Как понять что аккаунт полностью соответствует всем правилам и как правильно ввести адрес чтобы перейти к оплате аккаунта?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку